# Help with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

Using mod_rewrite I want to rewrite a sub directory like this:

From `http://www.example.com/sub/index.php?page=index` to `http://www.example.com/sub/index`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "index" on second line is index from "index.php" or from page=index

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ /$1/index.php?page=$2
```

Here I say: "If you have an URL wich begins (`^` is the begining) with some letters (`[a-z]` means "*a letter in [a, b, ..., z]*", and `+` means "*one or more*"), then a slash, then again some letters, and nothing after (`$` means it is the end of the URL), rewrite it like this: the first group of letters, then a slash, then `index.php?page=`, then the second group."

A group is delimited with parentheses. `$n` means "*the n-th group*". If the sub directory is always the same, use this instead: `RewriteRule ^sub/([a-z]+)$ /sub/index.php?page=$1`.

Note that `http://www.example.com` before is implicit.

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/users/boudou -> http://www.example.com/users/index.php?page=boudou
http://www.example.com/files/cv -> http://www.example.com/files/index.php?page=cv
http://www.example.com/zzz/sleep -> http://www.example.com/zzz/index.php?page=sleep
```

Comment: That doesn't work, i'v also tried this but it won't work: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sub/([^/]*)$ /sub/index.php?page=$1 [L]`

Comment: Are you sure that `mod_rewrite` is activated on your server ?

Comment: Yes. This code is working but it has a prefix (user_), and i want to be without prefix `RewriteRule ^user_([^/]*)$ /sub/index.php?page=$1 [L]`

Comment: I'v solved the problem :) `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /sub/index.php?page=$1 [L] `